# My redirect from http to https via .htaccess is not working. I have read a number of posts here, but I can't figure out where my error is

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to re-direct an old php site (not WordPress) from http to https for a client. I read through a number of posts and all of the codes seemed slightly different and I don't know enough to find my error.

I tried this code, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monahanassociates\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://monahanassociates.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you basically want to apply https to any http call? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: _"but it's not working."_ - Not working how? What actually happens? No redirect is done? Errors? Nothing works? Server catches fire?

Comment: May it be that you missed "p" in word "examplesite" in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examlesite\.com [NC]<br/>`

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual code instead of posting it in comments

Comment: The site is still comimg up as http unless I manually add https in the browser. I tried clearing the cache and using an incognito browser

Comment: Can you, please, also, state which webserver do you use? nginx, apache, something else?

Comment: Did you enable the interpretation if distributed configuration files? How? And how did you test that _this_ file is actually considered?